# How to convert private key in PKCS#8 format to PKCS#1 format with M2Crypto

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, private-key, m2crypto

I have a private key in PKCS #8 format.  I see the following style of tags:

```
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
     xxxx
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I want to convert it to a PKCS #1 format with tags like this:

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    xxxxxx
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is there a way to do this using M2Crypto?

If I use an openssl command to do the conversion:

```
    openssl rsa -in originalkey.pem -out newkey.pem
```

I get an error:

```
    unable to load Private Key
    3071661804:error:0D078079:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:field missing:tasn_dec.c:501:Field=d, Type=RSA
    3071661804:error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib:rsa_ameth.c:115:
    3071661804:error:0606F091:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKCS82PKEY:private key decode error:evp_pkey.c:95:
    3071661804:error:0907B00D:PEM routines:PEM_READ_BIO_PRIVATEKEY:ASN1 lib:pem_pkey.c:132:
```

Any idea what that error means?

Answer (score -3):

```
#rsa key
cat pkcs8.pem | openssl rsa 2>/dev/null

#ec key
cat pkcs8.pem | openssl ec 2>/dev/nul
```

Comment: this is a answer or a question?

Comment: The community [encourages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712) adding explanations alongside code, rather than purely code-based answers. As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837): "While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value." Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score -4):

openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in pkcs8.pem -out pkcs1.pem